# In a javascript nested object, How to get all parents attribute chain by a property like id?(If possible, vanilla javascript)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

My object list looks like this:

```
  const a = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'NewYork',
        children: [],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Tokyo',
        children: [
          {
            id: 7,
            name: 'Toshima',
            children: [],
          },
          {
            id: 8,
            name: 'Minato',
            children: [
              {
                id: 17,
                name: 'Sugamo',
                children: [],
              },
              {
                id: 18,
                name: 'Kamiichi',
                children: [],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
```

And now I have an id 18, I'd like to make a String like `Tokyo>Minato>Kamiichi`

How can I make it work in javascript (no third party library) ?

Actually I have a very long nested object.

Comment: Depends, I think you need to clarify a behaviour. Just getting that specific data when you know the ID's is not a problem, and if it is then this question should be flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: "*How can I make it work in javascript (no third party library) ?*" then why have you tagged Lodash and Underscore?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a recursive function for this:

```js
const a = {
  companies: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'NewYork',
      children: [],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Tokyo',
      children: [{
          id: 7,
          name: 'Toshima',
          children: [],
        },
        {
          id: 8,
          name: 'Minato',
          children: [{
              id: 17,
              name: 'Sugamo',
              children: [],
            },
            {
              id: 18,
              name: 'Kamiichi',
              children: [],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};


function getPath(obj, id) {
  if (obj.id === id) return obj.name;
  for (const child of obj.children) {
    const path = getPath(child, id);
    if (path) {
      return obj.name ? obj.name + '>' + path : path;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(getPath({
  children: a.companies
}, 18));
```

Comment: Thank you ! You are nice!

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot use word ``for`` because of TypeScript no-restricted-syntax error. Is there a way to use `reduce ` or something else instead of  `for` ?

Comment: @chii `no-restricted-syntax` error is user specified. Why do you disallow `for`? It's [ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/2.13.1/rules/no-restricted-syntax) and not TypeScript. You should just remove this rule.

Comment: Oh...it is the rule in my project which i cannot change it>< But I managed to get it work by using ``for (let i = 0; i < len; i += 1)``

Comment: @chii Why can't you change it? Your approach is much worse. Just remove the `no-restricted-syntax` rule or add a `eslint-disable no-restricted-syntax`. Don't flaw your code because of nonsense rules.

Comment: yes, you are right, and I will have a try!